# What is the difference in pronunciation of "Nichts" and "Nics"?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation, standard-german

Often I hear different pronunciations for the word

> Nichts

Some people pronounce it as

> Nics

(Well, it sounds like "Nics".)

Does it make any difference? Is this a different dialect? Is it good to use as "Nics"?

Comment: A related phrase: "Ein Satz mit x, das war wohl nix", which is a humorous way to comment on failure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's actually

> [nix](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nix)

It's slang for *nichts*, as you have guessed.

---

<sup>I'd love to say something more but, first, I'd like to understand what is "good to use" (obviously, don't write *nix* it in a formal context!), and, secondly, I'm not an expert. Whence I'm pretty sure somebody will illuminate us with a better answer.</sup>

Comment: nix is shorter and easier to pronounce than nichts. Obviously, you shouldn't use it in written german. If you're dealing with friends, it's ok to shorten it.

Comment: As I am learning German, it is just a suggestion I need on when to be used and not to be used.

Comment: I think this is an ordinary dialect word.

Comment: To a learner I would recommend to use the standard pronunciation.

Answer (score 15):

*Nix* is, as was already pointed out, a colloquial, informal, shorter form of *nichts*.

*Nix* ***does not*** derive from any specific dialect; rather it is present in one form or another in most dialects. There are exceptions like the Berlin dialect prefering *nüscht*.

User Mach suppied [a map in the comments](https://regionalsprache.de/Map/LvlwDfEL) which is scrollable and zoomable at least on PC which shows the distribution of various predominant forms prior to World War I. It can be seen that the largest contiguous area that does not use *nix* is comprised approximately the current states of the current states of Thuringia, Saxony, Saxony-Anhalt, Berlin and Brandenburg with some parts of southeastern Lower Saxony added; in this area *nischt* or *nüscht* are the predominant forms. This area used to extend far eastwards but to the best of my knowledge there are no longer significant German-speaking minorities there after World War II. The map excludes German-speaking areas of Belgium, Luxembourg, Switzerland, Liechtenstein and Austria; for most of these areas one can extend the closest form used in Germany outwards but I would be hesitant to generalise for German-speaking Switzerland, Liechtenstein and the Vorarlberg region of Austria. I am fairly confident that the other parts of Austria and South Tyrol will again fit into the *nix* area.

It is okay to use in very informal writings, like text messages to friends or in a chat etc. Do not use it in any kind of more official written context; even in a letter to good friends, I would spell out *nichts* 99 % of the time.

It is also okay to use it in most contexts when speaking. (e.g: If my supervisor asks me if I had any success in an experiment, I can hear myself answering *da hab ich nix rausbekommen* but if I were in a job interview, I would make sure to use *nichts* most of the time.)

There are people (like me) who will pronounce *nix* in almost every spoken context while there are others that will pronounce *nichts* more often; I think that this is due to speaker's preference.

Comment: The assertion that the form «nix» “is present in one form or another in most dialects” is obviously wrong, as you yourself immediately prove in the next sentence. And Berlin dialect is not a rare exception, but just one of many dialects that use a form other than «nix».

Comment: @mach *most* does not mean *all*. I maintain that an overwhelming majority of dialects will have such a form and that other forms are much rarer even when aggregated.

Comment: And I maintain that you are mistaken. And this is not just my opinion against yours, but I have proof, see [Wenker-Atlas: _nichts_](https://regionalsprache.de/Map/LvlwDfEL) (hope the link works).

Comment: @mach The link seems to work and presents a very large *nix* area, not-so-large parts of *nex* or *niksch* (clearly related as per my original point), some also not-so-large parts with *niz* or *nis/nüs* (potentially related). The clear exceptions are the south-western Rhineland (Mosel/Saar into Belgium), central Hessia and the East except for Mecklenburg and Western Pommerania (including areas around Braunschweig). Some parts of the extreme South-West and Switzerland seem to use *nit* which may or may not be related to *niz/nis* and thus may or may not fit entirely. (cont.)

Comment: Over half of the non-*nix* and related area was lost post-1945 and there are no longer significant German-speaking populations there to the best of my knowledge. Thus, I conclude that my statement was close enough to correct to be sustained.

Comment: @Jan _nit_ (in the southwest) goes with _ned_ (Bavarian areas) and possibly _net_ (more northern) as generic negation and short for _nicht_.

Comment: @Raffzahn However, it is included on a map that otherwise maps forms and variations of *nix*. Are you suggesting that these areas do not distinguish between forms a Standard German speaker would identify as *nichts* and *nicht*?

Comment: @Jan Jup. At least in several common situations. After all, words and their usage are not always a 1:1 between dialects. Or are they?

Comment: @Raffzahn No, they aren't but I wasn't aware that a distinction was lost in these dialects! In that case, the *nit* areas do *not* fit my bill of being essentially the same as *nix* in a different dialect, I presume. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Jan While I do think your definition is quite worthwhile, I wouldn't go as far as saying it has been 'lost'. For the case made, I would include it at least as remark.

Answer (score 2):

"Nix" is dialectal. Dialects which have this form exist in Northern Germany and in Bavaria. Because of this wide range, it can also be used in colloquial speech as most/all Germans will understand it. It is not slang, but use of this form might have a surprise value that would stress the message of "nothing".

By the way, "ik" is not a different way of saying "ich". Actually, it is an older form that predates the High German consonant shift and exists in dialects in which this shift has not fully taken effect, i.e. in the North.

Answer (score 1):

*Nix* is basically the up-coming new, simplified pronunciation of *nichts*. As it is still rather young, it's not yet considered 'proper' German but purely colloquial, so the spelling has not been updated, and so, when you find the word *nichts* in a written text, you can't pronounce it *nix* when reading it aloud. It has a status similar to *it's* for *it is* and many other similar contractions in English, except it's still a bit more informal. *Nix* is how it is spelled when it does occur in written German, typically in informal dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP's question has yet to be fully addressed--even the *accepted answer* does not really do the job--allow me to point out the difference in pronunciation. To an English speaker, **nix** sounds like "nicks," whereas **nichts** is much different. The **ch** sound in the German does not exist in either British or American English.

It may be described as a hollow, windy sound made near the back of the throat, and if air is not passing over your tongue when you say the **ch**-sound, you aren't saying it correctly.

Many speakers of English mistakenly articulate the German **ch** as a "k" phoneme. Common examples of butchered pronunciations are the simple German words **doch** (mispronounced as "dock") and **Ich** (misspoken as "ick").

But the **ch** sounds neither like a "k" nor an "sh," thus **nichts** is not properly pronounced as either "niks" or "nishts." To get help learning the correct tongue position for the **ch**-sound, practice the starting sound of English words like "Hugh" or "huge," as this is probably the closest approximation to the German **ch** an English speaker has.

Comment: In "nichts" there is no hard ch sound at all. It's similar to English "sh" as in "English" (in some dialects even identical). In "nix" there's isn't anything special either. It's like "ks" in "fix".

Comment: On a side note: Some Germans pronounce "ich" as "ick" in their dialect.

Comment: @Em1, I suppose "hard" was meant in the sense of "difficult". I was perplexed by this as well.

Comment: The question on the table is: **What is the difference in pronounciation [sic] of “Nichts” and “Nics”?** To be clear, the accepted response explaining the slang relationship between those two words does not answer the question. Further, the response explaining the acceptability of pronouncing _nix_ over _nichts_, without once describing the actual difference in the sound of those two words, does not address the OP's question either.

Comment: @Carsten: I understood the question quite well. My criticisms were not attacks and ought not to be taken as such. I merely pointed out the two responses prior to mine did not address the OP's headline question.

Comment: @Em1: You are correct there is no "hard" ch sound in nichts. Thank you for pointing that out. That was sloppy of me and I've amended my answer. As for your side note, I recognize the ch sound will be spoken differently in Bavaria than Swabia, not to mention Hochdeutsch, but anyone with language experience realizes that too. For example, an American English phonetics primer will not teach Appalachian children in Kentucky to pronounce "fight the fire" as "fit the far," even though that's exactly how some of them are going to pronounce it regardless of "standard" phonetics rules.

Comment: @Em1:  Explaining that "Ich" and "ick" don't sound the same, and then having the exceptions pointed out to that "rule," are what make languages so much fun in the first place! :-)